# PowerBi subtracting two cells in different rows with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am wondering if something that i would like to achieve is possible, please look at the picture and read description below:

[image]

I would like to add a column to the right, where if a cell table[ActionType] = "TERMINATING", it calculates a difference between timestamps (timestamp for TERMINATING - timestamp for STARTING in below row). If the result is positive (>0) then store it in a column in a corresponding row (eg next to timestapm for terminating), if result is negative don't store it. And all of that applied to whole table.

I tried conditional column and i guess it cannot be done with this or at least I couldn't make it.

Will be very thankful for responses and tips!

Comment: how do you keep track of which 'Terminating' belongs with which 'Starting' ?  If there's some kind of identifying field that is unique to each pair, you can unpivot the columns and do the math very easily from there.

Comment: No there is no specific way to determine it. Operations are ordered chronographically - newest in the top. So pair it would be top TERMINATING and STARTING right below it. I am interested only in positive values - as termination is always after starting so timestamps subtracting has to give positive result. Do you know what would be the formula for subtracting second from first, fourth from third and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pre-requisite :- Add an Index Column using the query editor. Make sure they are in the next row to each other.**

It is advisable to keep TimeStamp column as a DateTime Column itself.

So, if you can change your TimeStamp column to a DateTime column then try this :-

```
Difference = 
   Var Get_Action_Type = Table1[ActionType]
   Var required_Index_1 = Table1[Index] + 1
   Var required_Index = IF(required_Index_1 > MAX(Table1[Index]),required_Index_1-1, required_Index_1)
   Var Current_Action_TimeStamp = Table1[TimeStamp]
   Var next_Action_TimeStamp = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[TimeStamp]),FILTER(Table1, Table1[Index] = required_Index))
   Var pre_result = IF(Get_Action_Type = "TERMINATING", DATEDIFF(Current_Action_TimeStamp, next_Action_TimeStamp,SECOND), BLANK())
   Var result = IF(pre_result > 0, pre_result, BLANK())
return result
```

And if you cannot change it to a Date Time, then try this calculated column,

```
Difference_2 = 
   Var Get_Action_Type = Table1[ActionType]
   Var required_Index_1 = Table1[Index] + 1
   Var required_Index = IF(required_Index_1 > MAX(Table1[Index]),required_Index_1-1, required_Index_1)
   Var Current_Action_TimeStamp = Table1[Time_Stamp_Number]
   Var next_Action_TimeStamp = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Time_Stamp_Number]),FILTER(Table1, Table1[Index] = required_Index))
   Var pre_result = IF(Get_Action_Type = "TERMINATING", next_Action_TimeStamp - Current_Action_TimeStamp, BLANK())
   Var result = IF(pre_result > 0, pre_result, BLANK())
return result
```

The Output looks as below :-

[image]

*Kindly accept the answer if it helps and do let me know, how it works for you.*

Comment: Thanks for response. I am trying it out but somehow i am not getting any results out of it: https://imgur.com/a/DYzvKFx do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Actually it is second answer, just erased _2 from Difference_2

Comment: Working! Thanks!